# Почему не работает innerHTML при попытке добавить данные с сервера?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

На сервере пытаюсь добавить данные к существующей HTML странице.

сервер

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

//БД
const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';

async function getCards() {
    await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        cardsData = json.data.map(el => {
            return `
                <div class="col col--hidden" >
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="${el.avatar}" class="card-img-top"  width="200" height="200" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">${el.first_name} ${el.last_name}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">${el.email}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
        });
        JSDOM.fromFile('index.html').then( (dom) => {
            let cards = dom.window.document.getElementById('cards');
            cards.innerHTML =  '<p>ДОБАВилСЯ!</p>';
        })
    })
}



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    getCards();
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('index.html'));
});

server.listen(3000, (err) =>{
    if(err){
        throw Error(err);
    }
    console.log('Server is runnig');
});
```

клиент

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Business Cards</title>
    <style>

        html {
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .col--hidden {
            display: none;
            margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        }
        .row {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 250px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .card:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        .card-group {
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }
        .col {
            align-items: center;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        #img {
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        }

        .loadMore {
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            width: 500px;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Business Cards</span>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div id="cards" class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3"></div>
    <div class="card-group justify-content-center">
        
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="loadMore" class="loadMore"> Load More </a>

    <footer>
        <div class="text-center p-4" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
            © Nimchenko Anastasiya 2021
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(function(){
                $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(".col--hidden").slice(0,3).slideDown().removeClass('col--hidden');

                    $(this).toggle();
                })})
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что он не работает?

Comment: @Grundy потому что на моей странице не появляется "ДОБАВилСЯ!"

Comment: А разве результат (измененная разметка) выводится куда-то? Я вижу только отправку из файла. Если измененная разметка выводится, уточни где в коде ее вывод, пожалуйста. А если она не выводится - то вопрос некорректен, т.к. проблемы в общем-то нет ...

Comment: @yar85 измененная разметка должна рендерится к клиентская сторона сервера вот здесь

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    getCards();
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('index.html'));
});

Comment: @name4less, в коде нигде не меняется сам файл.

Comment: Нет, не должна, т.к. это отправка файла с накопителя (без изменений) - а изменения ты похоже не сохраняешь и не отправляешь. Если так, то получается что заключение "`innerHTML` не работает" ложно, а значит и вопрос некорректен (на него невозможно дать ответ). Допиши свой код, и он вероятно заработает без каких-либо проблем. То что недописанный код работает не полностью - проблемой не является строго говоря, это просто недоделанная работа.

Comment: @yar85 OK. и если не знаю как дописать, создавать новую тему?

Comment: Ну, лучше будет научиться и попытаться решить самостоятельно, чем "темы" на вопросном сайте создавать. То есть, незнание является поводом для изучения, но не для создания псевдовопросов со смыслом "сделайте за меня, а то мне лень читать документацию JSDOM" - такое участники заминусят и закроют, надеюсь что сам понимаешь почему.

Comment: @yar85 мне на хабре ответили, что мне нужно получить HTML после изменения элемента и передать этот HTML как ответ. И я перешерстила очень много форумов и сайто, чтобы найти ответ, но у меня ничего не вышло.
А документацию JSDOM я прочитала всю с самого начала.
Но у меня слишко мало опыта, чтобы справится с этой проблемой (еще даже не Junior).

Comment: Так никто сеньорами не рождается - для того чтобы повышать свой уровень, требуется учиться и развиваться. А смысл обучения как раз в том, чтобы понимать теорию и применять ее практически (решая задачи). У тебя есть задача, это прекрасно, можешь на ее решении научиться. Если же развиваться не хочешь, то есть хочешь чтобы поработали за тебя - ну без проблем, оплачивай время фрилансера, и он тебе все сделает... только это уже на других сайтах (stackoverflow не фриланс-портал, а база знаний: сообщество здесь помогает когда возникают трудности в процессе обучения, но не выполняет работу на заказ).

Comment: На хабре ответили верно - то есть, уже и алгоритм тебе дали готовый, осталось только кодом его записать. _«А документацию JSDOM я прочитала всю с самого начала.»_ - значит надо повторить прочтение, снова и снова, пока не прочтется раздел "Serializing the document with serialize()". Затем прочесть любую статью об отправке строк через Express (например, в официальной документации этого фреймворка), и все пробелы в знаниях необходимых для решения задачи, будут успешно закрыты. Извини за прямоту, но завершить решение тебе мешает именно лень, а не какие-то проблемы из области программирования.

Comment: @yar85 знаете, легко говорить, когда есть достаточно опыта и так сказать "судить со своей колокольни"..

Comment: @yar85 спасибо за подсказку о serialize

Comment: Мой опыт здесь не имеет значения - любой другой участник мог бы точно так же объяснить и суть процесса обучения, и назначение stackoverflow. Тут много и джуниоров которые все это понимают.